# Ruby: Why symbols change to strings when using puts instead of print?

Tags: ruby, printing

I don't understand the behavior of print and puts?
I know print would not make a new line but puts can.
but why the output of print will change from symbol to string when using puts instead of print?

`$ ruby -e 'print Kernel.private_instance_methods(false)'

```
[:initialize_copy, :remove_instance_variable, :sprintf, :format, :Integer, :Float, :String, :Array, :warn, :raise, :fail, :global_variables, :__method__, :__callee__, :eval, :local_variables, :iterator?, :block_given?, :catch, :throw, :loop, :caller, :trace_var`
```

$ ruby -e 'puts Kernel.private_instance_methods(false)'

```
initialize_copy
remove_instance_variable
sprintf
format
Integer
Float
String
Array
warn
raise
fail
global_variables
__method__
__callee__
eval
local_variables
```

Comment: `print s` behaves more like `puts s.inspect`. `puts`ing an `Array` will display each array element on a new line. Or so I believeth.

Comment: @Zabba `p()` is a Kernel method that write's `obj.inspect` to the standard output. Not print.

Comment: @Kit Ho: I haven't see difference between puts ant print working with symbols. May be you mean method `p()`? http://pastie.org/3743547

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `puts`, what really gets called is the `rb_io_puts` C function, which basically works like this:

- If there is no argument, output a newline.
- For each argument check if it's of type string (`T_STRING` in Ruby C lingo) and if yes, call `rb_io_write` with it. Also, if the string was of length zero or didn't finish in a newline, add a `\n`.
- If the argument is an array, recursively call `io_puts_ary` on it.
- In any other case, call `rb_obj_as_string` on the argument, which basically is the low-level equivalent of `to_s`.

So when you `puts [:a, :b, :c]`, you'll hit the third case and `io_puts_ary` will take over. Long story short this will do something similar as what I described above, and will call `rb_obj_as_string` on each element and output it followed by a newline.

Answer (score 0):

The print function  will call array's to_s function,
the array's to_s function is the alias of inspect function.

This can be found in ruby's array.c code.

```
rb_define_alias(rb_cArray,  "to_s", "inspect");
```

Therefore:

```
array = Kernel.private_instance_methods(false)
$stout.write(array.to_s)
```

will also output the same result.